# set label value in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, label

I'm usually a PHP guy but got stuck doing a project in vb.net.

I have a query (sqldatasource) that returns a single value (the last update date).

I want to use a label to say something like "Last updated: " < Label = (returned value) >

In PHP this would be simple. In vb.net, all I can find are endless badly written code behinds showing how you'd execute the query onLoad then bind it to the label.

Is this really the only way to do this? It seems like a ridiculously simple problem to have such a long solution. I have used a datagrid control to just bind the query result directly, but it prints the column name as well as the date, so it's not ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: If all you want to display is the last updated (single field), then no point using datagrid. Just use a ADO.NET DataReader, plenty of examples around.

Here's one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Page_Load method, run your query.  On your page.aspx, you have a form control, lets call it label1.  Set label1.text = queryResult.

```
Sub Page_Load()
  dim myConnection as new data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
  dim myCommand as new data.sqlclient.sqlcommand
  dim sqlReader as data.sqlclient.sqldatareader
  myConnection.connectionString = 'enter your connection string details'
  myConnection.Open()
  myCommand = New SqlCommand("Select lastUpdated from yourTable", myConnection)
  sqlReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
  if sqlReader.hasRows then
    sqlReader.read()
    label1.text = Format("MM/dd/yyyy", sqlReader("lastUpdated"))
  end if
End Sub
```

And your page.aspx (somewhere)

```
<asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" />
```

PS - I may be off on the format function above, been awhile.

EDIT based on user comment:

Well, for what you are doing, I wouldn't really recommend a SQLDataSource as it is really meant to be bound to a control such as a gridview or repeater.  However, if you want to use the SQLDataSource, you will need to bind to a DataView in your code-behind.  From there, you can access each row (you should only have one) and column by name.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dv As New Data.DataView
    'use the id of your SqlDataSource below'
    dv = SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    Label1.Text = dv.Table.Rows(0)("LastUpdated")
End Sub
```

TO use a connection string from the web.config:

Web.Config File:

```
<appSettings>  
   <add key="strConnectionString" value="Data Source=192.168.0.55;Database=Times;User ID=sa;PassWord=sa"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Code Behind:

```
     Dim sqlConn as new data.sqlClient.SqlConnection()
     sqlConn.ConnectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("strConnectionString").ConnectionString
     sqlConn.Open()
```

Comment: thanks Tommy-- can you explain how I'd use a SqlDataSource with this approach? Or, if that's not possible or advisable, how to use a predefined connection string with this code?

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate you taking the time to help with this. I think I'm very close, but for some reason I"m not getting any data to print. I switched from the sqldatasource to a code behind approach as you recommended, and to test I added an "else" clause to the 
    If sqlReader.HasRows then
        sqlReader.Read()
        label.Text = Format("MM/dd/yyyy", sqlReader("LastUpdate"))
    Else
        label.Text = "no data"
    End If

this seems like it'd work-- but no value gets printed. Any ideas?

Comment: got it, needed to add "Handles Me.Load" to the page load function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I shorthanded the page_load function and shouldn't have.  Here is the full correct page_load line for your code:  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load.

PROTIP: (always wanted to use that!): In VS when you are in the code-behind, you will see two drop-downs at the top of the code window. The left one is for objects that this page has access to (labels, grids, etc.).  The right one is for methods and events for that object.  Choose (page events) from the left one, then (load) from the right one.  Does an auto generate.

Comment: ..of the correct method signatures for you.  No problem, happy learning.  .NET is a wide and powerful framework.  My first couple of projects and still now, I find myself discovering faster/better/different ways of doing the same things.